# How can to export Google maps data and understand them for creating new navigation software

Tags: google-maps, navigation

I want to create a navigation software and I need strong maps.
How can to export Google maps data and understand them for creating new navigation software?
Is it illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot export Google maps data. In fact you aren't even allowed to cache them:

> When using Google Maps or Earth APIs, you may not cache any imagery or
>   other Content. Google continually updates the imagery within Maps and
>   Earth; thus, caching may result in stale or even impermissible
>   imagery. For full details, please read section 10.3.1 of the [Maps/Earth API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en).

All google maps usage must be through the appropriate google maps API which specifically forbids turn-by-turn navigation if that is where you were going with this.

As an alternative you can try [openstreetmap.org](http://openstreetmap.org) and check out their [API usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy)

Basically you can download the entire planet as vectorized data from various [planet.osm mirrors](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this first http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html:

> Unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), you must not: (a) copy, translate, modify, or make derivative works of the Content or any part thereof; (b) redistribute, sublicense, rent, publish, sell, assign, lease, market, transfer, or otherwise make the Products or Content available to third parties; (c) reverse engineer, decompile or otherwise attempt to extract the source code of the Service or any part thereof, unless this is expressly permitted or required by applicable law

In other words, you're not allowed to extract their data.